# <header> <body> and <footer> tags don't work properly xhtml2pdf | django

Tags: html, django, xhtml2pdf

I'm using xhtml2pdf to render an html page to pdf and I would like to have a page header and a page footer which repeats for every new page. I've tried to use the tag `<header>` and `<footer>` of html but actually these don't work: they just show up in the page right in the position I wrote the code.

Any idea of which could be the problem?

I've also problems in the pagination: I've already looked in stackoverflow for similar questions but I couldn't handle the problem.

MY **template.html** that has to render in pdf.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">

    table{
        padding-top: 10px;
        border-right: 1.5px solid black;
        border-left: 1.5px solid black;

    }
    .intestazione {
        padding-top: 10px;
        border-right: 0.5px solid black;
        border-left: 0.5px solid black;
    }
 
    .vuota {
        background-color: grey;
    }
    .vuota2{
        border-top: 0px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        border-left:0px;
        border-right:0px;
    }
    td{
        margin-left: 5px;
        border: 0.5px solid black;
    }
    th{
        border: 0.5px solid black;
    }

    .interno {
        border-top: 0.3px solid black;
        border-bottom: 0.3px solid black;
    }
    
    .center2 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 5%;
    }
    
 
</style>
<html>
    <header>
    <div class="center2">
        <table class="intestazione"> 
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" style="width:200px; height:200px;  padding-top:-20px; padding-bottom: -20px; padding-left: 5px"><img  src="image.png" size=100></td>
                <td style="font-size: 10px; width: 450px;"><center><b>MODULE</b></center></td>
                <td style="font-size: 10px; width:80px; height:30px"><center><b>MD74200AZ.003</b></center></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; width: 450px;"><center>TITLE</center></td>
                <td style="font-size: 10px;"><center>PAG. 1/6</center></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </header>

    <footer>BlaBla</footer>
    <br>
    <body>
   
        <table style="border-top: 1.5px solid black">
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">STRUTTURA</td>
                <td>{{att.Struttura}}</td> 
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">DATA</td>
                <td>{{att.Data}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
        <!-- etc etc -->
        </body>
```

My **views.py**:

```
def export_pdf(request, pk):
    att = MAIN.objects.get(id=pk)
   
    specs = Specifiche.objects.filter(ID_rich=pk)
    lista=[]
    for spec in specs:
        lista+=[spec.id]
    uns = Unicita.objects.filter(rifext__in=lista)
    crs = Criteri.objects.filter(ID_rich = pk)
    cons = Consumabili.objects.filter(ID_rich = pk)
    context = {'att': att, 'uns': uns, 'specs': specs, 'crs':crs, 'cons':cons}
    template = get_template('modulorichiesta.html')
    html = template.render(context)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1", "ignore")), result)
    response = HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type="application/pdf")
    filename = str(att.Protocollo) + str(timezone.now())
    content = "attachement; filename='%s'"%(filename)
    response["Content-Disposition"] = content
    return response
```

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: Now I've edited